# Copy module function declarations to global namespace

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I have declared forty or so functions inside a module, but there is also a method that copies each function to the global namespace (or any target object provided).

```
module JsHamcrest {
    declare function assertThat(actual: any, matcher: Matcher): void;

    // lots and lots of Matcher factory methods
    declare function bool(): Matcher;
    declare function func(): Matcher;
    declare function number(): Matcher;
    declare function object(): Matcher;
    declare function string(): Matcher;
    ...

    declare function copyMembers(target: any): void;
}
```

This allows developers to use the namespaced functions in JavaScript as-is via the module name

```
JsHamcrest.assertThat(5, JsHamcrest.number());
```

or copy them into the global namespace to improve readability.

```
JsHamcrest.copyMembers(window);

assertThat('foo', string());
```

The shortest solution I've come up with so far is to assign each function to a global variable:

```
var number = JsHamcrest.number;
```

But at least in PhpStorm the JSDoc isn't applied to the copies, and it's still prone to error (though less so).

tl;dr **How can I declare these top-level definitions without copy-pasting them and still have IDEs auto-complete with documentation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to "bulk" copy members into the global namespace (thankfully?), but you can use `import` instead of `var` and should get JSDoc information assuming your editor uses the TypeScript Language service:

[image]

Comment: The import works, but PhpStorm doesn't inherit the documentation or parameter type-hinting (on those that take parameters): `Type Script Import Statement Impl "bool" [jshamcrest.d.ts]`. It seems this *is* the only way to go, however, and I'll submit a feature request to PhpStorm.

Comment: I suppose you're probably the highest authority on this, but I'll leave the question open for a day in case someone comes up with a left-field solution. :)

Comment: The only left-field idea I have is that you write one version of your declaration (maybe the global one) and then auto-generate a wrapped version of the file as a copy (just top it with `module JsHamcrest {` and tail it with a `}`). You could do that with a batch file, although more graceful methods exist. This gives you one place to manage the declarations. I'm doing a similar trick to make code work as both internal and external modules: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201411/Blog/Creating-A-TypeScript-Module-For-Use-With-Internal-And-External-Modules/

Comment: @SteveFenton I've done similar things for other projects (I <3 code generation) and will probably do so here. I submitted a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14077) for WebStorm (basis of the plugin for PhpStorm) for anyone interested.